# Hide a Div with a button inside it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to hide a div using an element which is **inside** it. I tried using a button and JavaScript as well as hacking a checkbox but none worked.
Here is my code thanks in advance for the help!!!

```
<style>

 #out_box{
  background: rgba(0,0,20,0.56);
height:30vh;
width:20vw;
}
 #hide_div:checked~#out_box{
  display:none;}

</style>


<html>
<body>
 <?php
  echo"<div id='out_box'>
    <button type='button' 
     id='hidebybtn> 
      BtnHideDiv <button>
    <input type='checkbox' 
     id='hide_div'>
    <Label for='hide_div'> 
     ChkHideDiv </label>
  </div>";
  
  if(isset($_GET['hidebybtn'])){ 
  echo"
   <script>
     const targetdiv = document.getElementById("out_box");
     const btn = document.getElementById ("hidebybtn");
btn.onclick( function (){ 
 targetdiv.style.display = "none";
);
   </script>
  ";
}
?>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't you have a PHP syntax error showing? Demo: https://3v4l.org/TATJq . If you don't, you need to enable PHP error reporting to help you with your debugging! Obviously putting a `"` inside a string which is delimited by `"` is never going to work. But why _echo_ a script in the first place? Just end your PHP block, include the JS code, and start your PHP block again. It's much more readable and you won't run into unnecessary problems with syntax and escaping (due to trying to cram one language into a string var of another). Demo: https://3v4l.org/OV0iL . The previous echo is pointless too!

Comment: If you want to hide a div by clicking a button, why not adding/removing a class with `display: none !important` via javascript?

Comment: Yeah sure...it should be a single qoute i made a mistake there...the reason why i put JS code inside PHP is that i tried earlier to write it seperate when i was displaying it in block bt it didn't work except i put it like that

Comment: Ok but it's a trivial mistake which should have been obvious if you'd have error reporting enabled - or if you'd used a code editor which can highlight syntax issues in PHP, you'd have seen it before you even tried to run the code. `the reason why i put JS code inside PHP`...what _is_ the reason, exactly?

Comment: I just edited the reason on the my comment above

Comment: `i tried earlier to write it seperate when i was displaying it in block bt it didn't work `...well it's a bit unclear why that was...my demo proves doing that would work just fine.

Comment: You can't select a parent of an element in CSS. Just a child or siblings, but not parents. `~` is a sibling selector you are using trying to select the parent of `.hide_div`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax needs to be fixed. Your requirement can be simply fixed by using js and css. Here's a code you can try:

```js
const targetdiv = document.getElementById('out_box');
const btn = document.getElementById ('hidebybtn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  targetdiv.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#out_box{
  background: rgba(0,0,20,0.56);
  height:30vh;
  width:20vw;
}
```

```html
 <body>
   <div id='out_box'>
     <button type='button' id='hidebybtn'> BtnHideDiv </button>
   </div>
</body>
```